# python numpy.libalg.eigh() returns wrong eigen vectors. why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, physics, numerical-methods

For a brief info,  I was tasked to model a wave function for a quantum particle imprisoned in a parabolic potential (this problem is related to quantum harmonic oscillator).
I used matrix method for 1D Schrodinger equation. After I constructed it properly (the matrix is tridiagonal one which is important) I used np.eigh to find the eigen vectors of this matrix, which are waves function that correspond to the energy states of this particle (eigen values from the matrix).
the numpy method returns proper eigen values, but it unfortunately returned wrong eigen vectors.
here is the numerical solution from numpy for ground state of the particle (plotted with matplotlib), the yellow curve is exact solution for comparison:
[image: numpy numerical solution]

As you see, the solution is not even close, so I used my own function to generate the eigen vector for a tridiagonal matrix. This numerical solution gives:
[image: own numerical solution]

Which is what I wanted. The question is why numpy method returns wrong eigen vector? Is it becouse it does it very poor for large matrices, or is it becouse it handles very poor with tridiagonal matrices? I run built in test for this module and its says it is all OK with it...

```py
>>> np.linalg.test()
Running unit tests for numpy.linalg
NumPy version 1.11.2
NumPy relaxed strides checking option: False
NumPy is installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
Python version 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
nose version 1.3.7
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 134 tests in 6.935s
OK
nose.result.TextTestResult run=134 errors=0 failures=0
```

The code I have written is in python 2.7.12 :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
###global variables###

N=100 #always -1 from real number of points
L=2 ##Calculation box length,too large spoils the solution!
dx=2.*L/(N+-0.) #calculation step
N=N+1
ax_x=[] #stores x values
ax_v=[] #stores potential values corresponding to x
omega=10. #parabole parameter
######################

def fill_matrix(ax_pot):
    matrix=[]
    for i in range(N):
        matrix.append([])
        for j in range(N):
            matrix[i].append(0.)
    for i in range(N):
        matrix[i][i]=1./(dx*dx)+ax_pot[i]
        if i != N-1:
            matrix[i][i+1]=matrix[i+1][i]=1./ ( 2.*(dx*dx) )
    return matrix


def fill_pot_par(ax_x,omega):
    for i in range(N):
        ax_v.append(ax_x[i]*ax_x[i]/2.*omega*omega)

def get_eig_val_id(e_vals,number_counted_from_smallest=0):
    evals=sorted(e_val)
    wsk=None
    for i in range(len(evals)):
        if e_vals[number_counted_from_smallest] == evals[i]:
            wsk=i
            break
    return wsk

def hermit_f_0(x):
    return 1

def get_analytical_solution(x_vec,e_val,omega_):
    new_x_vec=[]
    for i in range(len(x_vec)):
        new_x_vec.append(-x_vec[i]*x_vec[i]*omega_/2.)

    omega_sqrt=np.sqrt(omega_)
    new_x_vec=np.exp(new_x_vec)
    h_vec=[]
    print(e_val)
    if e_val == 0:
        for i in x_vec:
            h_vec.append(hermit_f_0(i*omega_sqrt))
    for i in range(len(new_x_vec)):
        new_x_vec[i]=new_x_vec[i]*h_vec[i]
    norm=0
    for i in new_x_vec:
        norm=norm+i*i
    norm=np.sqrt(norm)
    for i in range(len(new_x_vec)):
        new_x_vec[i]=new_x_vec[i]/norm
    return new_x_vec

def get_eig_vector(matrix,selfval):
    e_vec=[]
    sv=selfval
    sigma=0
    ga=matrix[0][1]
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        if i == 0:
            e_vec.append(1.)
            continue
        if i == 1:
            sigma=matrix[0][0]
            e_vec.append((sv-sigma)/ga)
            continue
        sigma=matrix[i-1][i-1]
        tmp_val=(sv-sigma)*e_vec[i-1]/ga-e_vec[i-2]
        e_vec.append(tmp_val)
    #print(e_vec)
    norm=0
    for i in e_vec:
        norm=norm+i*i
    norm=np.sqrt(norm)
    for i in range(len(e_vec)):
        e_vec[i]=e_vec[i]/norm
    return e_vec

if __name__ == "__main__":


    #filling axis
    for i in range(N):
        ax_x.append(-L+i*dx)

    fill_pot_par(ax_x,omega)

    #matrix to solve
    h_mat=fill_matrix(ax_v)

    #numpy method
    e_val,e_vec=np.linalg.eigh(h_mat)

    #becouse numpy returns the values in random order
   #you need to get the lowest by yourself
    wsk=get_eig_val_id(e_val,0)

    #my solution
    my_vector=get_eig_vector(h_mat,e_val[wsk])

    #analytical solution
    an_sol=get_analytical_solution(ax_x,0,omega)    

    #plotting
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax2=ax1.twinx()

    ax1.plot(ax_x,an_sol,'y',ax_x,e_vec[wsk],'b',ax_x,my_vector,'g')
    ax2.plot(ax_x,ax_v,'r')

    for t in ax1.get_yticklabels():
        t.set_color('b')
    for t in ax2.get_yticklabels():
        t.set_color('r')    
    plt.show()
```

EDIT: @Warren Weckesser solved my question. The problem is in plotting e_vec[wsk] instead of e_vec[:, wsk] thanks!

Comment: It would help if you created a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could run to reproduce the problem.  A simplified version of your code should be sufficient.

Comment: Your code shows that you plot `e_vec`, but `e_vec` will be a square matrix, so the plot should show *all* the eigenvectors. That's not what the plot shown in the question looks like.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to plot `e_vec[:, wsk]`?  That would be the eigenvector associated with `e_val[wsk]`.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser Yes i know. I have deleted the [] tags when posting question so previously it was correct. The code above runs fine for me.

Comment: Thanks.  The updated code shows the problem.  The eigenvectors are the *columns* of `e_vec`, so you must plot `e_vec[:, wsk]`, not `e_vec[wsk]`.

Comment: Oh I see now. I must have missed this when reading manual. Thanks for answering, now both methods gives same solutions. I will keep that in mind when using numpy eigh method. :)